# rails - apply complex visibility settings to thinking sphinx results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, thinking-sphinx

in the product i'm developing, i have a Message model.

Message can be restricted to groups, or not restricted (available to
everyone).

If user belongs to one of Message's groups OR message is not
restricted, user can see the message.

here is the query selecting visible messages (in hope that it can
clarify what i mean)

(2,3,4,5,6,1) are the groups user belongs to, they are different for
each user

```
SELECT `messages`.* FROM `messages`

LEFT JOIN groups_messages ON
messages.id=groups_messages.message_id AND groups_messages.group_id in (2,3,4,5,6,1)

 WHERE (messages.restricted=0 OR groups_messages.group_id is not NULL)

GROUP BY messages.id
```

here is analogical query using a subquery, in hope it helps to clarify what is needed

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE 
(
 restricted=0 OR id in ( select distinct message_id from groups_messages where group_id in  (2,3,4,5,6,1) )
 )
```

is it possible somehow to apply this visibility setting to thinking
sphinx results? meaning to apply this OR and IN to

```
Message.search "test" with/with_all
```

?

if it is not possible, another question would be - is it somehow
possible to get ids of all objects found in search,

so that i could perform query myself, just adding AND to my WHERE
condition

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE
(
 restricted=0 OR id in ( select distinct message_id from groups_messages where group_id in (2,3,4,5,6,1) )
)
AND id in (ids_of_the_messages_found_by_thinking_sphinx)
```

i imagine both the query without LEFT JOIN and adding AND to WHERE
will be a bit resource intensive for mysql, but if other solutions are
not possible, then this would do

thanks,

Pavel K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

received a response from Pat Allan, developer of Thinking Sphinx,

[link text](http://groups.google.com/group/thinking-sphinx/browse_thread/thread/5c5d8b7504c9c2d)

> I think the best way is to build a string that includes 0 if the
>   message is unrestricted, otherwise returns the group ids, concatenated
>   together with commas... ie:
>   "2,3,4,5,6" or "0"
>
> So, you'll want to build a SQL snippet for an attribute, something
>   vaguely like:

```
has "IF(messages.restricted = 0, '0', GROUP_CONCAT (groups_messages.group_id SEPARATOR ','))", :as => :group_ids, :type => :multi
```

> And then for searching:

```
Message.search "foo", :with => {
 :group_ids => [0] + current_user.message_group_ids
}
```

> The SQL snippet will have to be different if you're using PostgreSQL, though... let me know if that's the case.

will try that